# Adding Color to StringForm PlotLabel

Tags: plotting, manipulate

I have:

```
Manipulate[
 If[reflection, Plot[{-func}, {x, -3, 3},
   PlotStyle -> Red,
   PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}},
   GridLines -> Automatic,
   PlotLabel -> StringForm["f(x) = ``", -func]],
  Plot[{func}, {x, -3, 3},
   PlotStyle -> Blue,
   PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}},
   GridLines -> Automatic,
   PlotLabel -> StringForm["f(x) = ``", func]]],
 {func, {Sqrt[x], Abs[x], x^2, x^3}},
 {reflection, {False, True}}]
```

I'd like to make my plot label red when reflection is true and blue if reflection is false. How do you add color to ``` StringForm["f(x) = ``", func] ```?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Red]` and 
`LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Blue]`

```
Manipulate[
 If[reflection, 
  Plot[{-func}, {x, -3, 3}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
   PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
   PlotLabel -> StringForm["f(x) = ``", -func], 
   LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Red]], 
  Plot[{func}, {x, -3, 3}, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
   PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
   PlotLabel -> StringForm["f(x) = ``", func], 
   LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Blue]]], {func, {Sqrt[x], Abs[x], 
   x^2, x^3}}, {reflection, {False, True}}]
```

[image: red]

### EDIT

Per request, changing the label and not the ticks can be done:

> Individually styled labels can be used with LabelStyle and have higher
>   priority
>   -a mathematica help page

So we change the label directive to one color and wrap the label in a style, which is given priority:

```
If[reflection,
  Plot[{-func}, {x, -3, 3}, PlotStyle -> Cyan, 
   PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}}, GridLines -> Automatic,
   PlotLabel -> Style[StringForm["f(x) = ``", -func], Red],   
   LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Magenta]], 
  Plot[{func}, {x, -3, 3},
   PlotStyle -> Cyan, PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}}, 
   GridLines -> Automatic, 
   PlotLabel -> Style[StringForm["f(x) = ``", -func], Blue], 
   LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Magenta]]], {func, {Sqrt[x], Abs[x], 
   x^2, x^3}}, {reflection, {False, True}}]
```

[image: diff colors]

[image: diff colors2]

Comment: Very easy solution. But I think I would like just my plot label to change colors and note the ticks. But thanks for a very nice easy answer.

Comment: @David also possible! check out the edits- I used outlandish colors to make each part obvious.

Comment: Thanks. These are some very nice options.